How do I consolidate the related mappings?
I have a table which has mappings coming from different sources (one row for each source) for three different identifier types (idtype1 to idtype3) with idtype1 having the highest priority and idtype3 lowest. I need to merge and consolidate all the related mappings, so that I can have a better view of the relations between them.
The initial table of mappings looks like:



idtype1
idtype2
idtype3




null
b
c


null
null
c


null
b
d


a
null
d


null
b
null


x
b
null



Now, as all the id types are somehow linked to each other,i.e. c linked to b which is linked to d, which is again linked to a, now, as x is related to b, all are essentially linked to each other. I should be able to consolidate the information into the below result:



idtype1
idtype2
idtype3




a
b
c


a
b
d


x
b
c


x
b
d



Example 2:



idtype1
idtype2
idtype3




null
null
c


null
b
c


null
null
d


a
null
d


null
b
d


null
null
e


null
b
e


null
b
null



I should consolidate this down to:



idtype1
idtype2
idtype3




a
b
c


a
b
d


a
b
e



Can anyone help come up with an efficient logic for this?
EDIT:
The table can have multiple such combinations, i.e. both the examples can be present at once with different values.
CREATE TABLE mappings (idtype1 VARCHAR(10),idtype2 VARCHAR(10),idtype3 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT mappings
VALUES
(null,null,'c'),
(null,'b','c'),
(null,null,'d'),
('a',null,'d'),
(null,'b','d'),
(null,null,'e'),
(null,'b','e'),
(null,'b',null),
(null,'q','r'),
(null,null,'r'),
(null,'q','s'),
('p',null,'s'),
(null,'q',null),
('t','q',null)


Output should be:



idtype1
idtype2
idtype3




a
b
c


a
b
d


x
b
c


x
b
d


p
q
r


p
q
s


p
q
t




tables a re by nature unsorted, so your wanted will not be possible, so you should add a solumn that joins the rows together

AFAICT your example 2 is flawed. a/b/e should be a valid path given {a//d, /b/d, /b/e}, right? Might be worth clarifying the requirements.

@PeterVandivier Yes, a/b/e is a valid path and this is why it is included in the output (last row). Essentially, I need to find all the possible combinations of the idtypes if they are linked in any manner.

Assuming..

you only have 3 levels
each letter can exist at only 1 level
implied relationships are transitive

e.g. a->b->c ∪ p->b->e ⇒ {a->b->e, p->b->c}



...then the following should be sufficient:
It's a bit messy but here's a full dbfiddle using the "edit" dataset sample.
First, isolate only those records that communicate a relationship (any row with 2 or 3 non-NULL values) like so. Singleton rows may communicate the existence of an otherwise orphaned entity, but will not provide any relevant mapping information.
(
  select 
    '1->2',
    idtype1,
    idtype2
  from mappings
  where idtype1 is not null
    and idtype2 is not null
)
union all
(
  select 
    '2->3',
    idtype2,
    idtype3
  from mappings
  where idtype2 is not null
    and idtype3 is not null
)
union all
(
  select 
    '1->3',
    idtype1,
    idtype3
  from mappings
  where idtype1 is not null
    and idtype3 is not null
)

Isolating just those rows gives us.



idtype1
idtype2
idtype3





b
c


a

d



b
d



b
e



q
r



q
s


p

s


t
q




From there, infer missing relationships. Because we assume only 3 levels exist, the only possible skip-level relationships are those with the 1->3 label. e.g.
  select * 
  from relationships
  where ancestor_level = 1
    and descendant_level = 3

Once you've normalised the relationships AND backfilled any gaps, you self-join the 1->2 & 2->3 relationships to get the complete set as seen below.
select 
  r1.ancestor_name as level_1,
  r2.ancestor_name as level_2,
  r2.descendant_name as level_3
from relationships as r1
join relationships as r2 on r2.ancestor_name = r1.descendant_name
order by 1, 2, 3

Given this approach, we assume the below solution:

Where red lines are inferred.



idtype1
idtype2
idtype3




a
b
c


a
b
d


a
b
e


p
q
r


p
q
s


t
q
r


t
q
s




This solution has a few open questions & caveats.

If a p->a relationship was introduced, would the transitivity apply such that a->q was now valid?
This solution only works for 3 levels. A 4th level would require additional relationship discovery. As levels increase, it becomes a more standard hierarchical recursion problem - the answer to which depends on whether p->a ⇒ a->q

An example of self-join vs. recursion for inferring hierarchy can be read about further at Find Ancestry From JSON

If you're after a single query that will produce the expected result, you'd probably need to do something like this (which is essentially building a set of each distinct, and non-null, "type" value, and then outputting the intersection of each).
;WITH 
t1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT idType1 FROM mapTable WHERE idType1 Is Not Null),
t2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT idType2 FROM mapTable WHERE idType2 Is Not Null),
t3 AS (SELECT DISTINCT idType3 FROM mapTable WHERE idType3 Is Not Null)
SELECT
*
FROM t1
CROSS APPLY t2
CROSS APPLY t3;

You talk about the different values having "links" to each other, which I'll admit, to me, doesn't make complete sense - but going by your "expected output" I'm assuming that it's the possible combinations of each type1, type2, type3 value that you're wanting

This query works perfectly fine if I have the table with all the values related to each other and there is only one such combination, however, I want the query to be flexible and work on multiple combinations of such relations. I have provided an example in the edit. Thanks!

You'll need to explain the logic behind how the combinations should appear.  In your third example, where does the "x" come from, and why is the "t" in the "Type3" column?
